# Проблема с локализацией сайта i18n (nuxt.js)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, i18n

Конфигурация i18n:

```
['nuxt-i18n', { 
      locales: [
        {
          name: 'Русский',
          code: 'ru',
          iso: 'ru-RU',
          file: 'ru-RU.js'
        },
        {
          name: 'English',
          code: 'en',
          iso: 'en-US',
          file: 'en-US.js'
        },
      ],
      langDir: 'lang/',
      defaultLocale: 'ru',
    }]
```

Русский файл:

```
export default {
    lang: 'Русский',
    navTitle: 'Доска Объявлений',
    filter: 'Фильтр'
}
```

Английский файл:

```
export default {
    lang: 'English',
    navTitle: 'Bulletin board',
    filter: 'Filter'
}
```

Пример вывода на страницу:

```
{{ $t('lang') }}
```

В итоге получаю ошибку:

```
[vue-i18n] Cannot translate the value of keypath 'lang'. Use the value of keypath as default.
```

Кто знает как решить, или есть какие-то мысли напишите пожалуйста буду очень признателен.

Comment: Доброй ночи. А файл у Вас случаем называется не `lang`? Добавьте чуть больше информации по названиям самих файлов и связок.

Comment: Нет, названия файлов - ru-RU.js и en-US.js Может ещё какую-то информацию предоставить?